# How can I send another variable with FileReference Upload?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a problem with the filereference class using the upload function.
I want to send the `folderLocation` variable with `fileReference.upload()`.
Below I try to describe my strategy.

```
var folderLocation : String = "photos/myUniqueFolder/";

private var serverSideScript:String = "http://localhost/project/phpFlexMechanism/upload.php";
urlRequest = new URLRequest(serverSideScript);

fileReferenceList.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectedHandler);

private function fileSelectedHandler(event:Event):void {
// upload the file to the server side script
        fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadCompleteHandler);
        fileReference.upload(urlRequest);
}
```

In PHP I use this to get the the file and uploaded

```
$folder = $_POST['folder'];

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];

move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "../user/$folder/uploadImages/" . $fileName);
```

But how can I send the `folder` through the "upload reference"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that, since you `FileReference` needs a `URLRequest`, you would be able to piggy back that information through the `URLRequest` itself by using the `flash.net.URLVariables` object.

I've not had time to test this, but have you tried:

```
// put this right after you instantiate urlRequest;
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVars.targetFolder     = folderLocation;
urlRequest.method        = "post";
urlRequest.data          = urlVar;
```

That should let you do:

```
//replace your last line with these two.
$folder = $_REQUEST[ "targetFolder" ];
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "../user/$folder/uploadImages/" . $fileName);
```

in PHP.

Comment: sorry for late.Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest thing you can do is just send it through with a get header in the upload function

so the code looks as follows

```
private var serverSideScript:String = "http://localhost/project/phpFlexMechanism/upload.php?extraVar=value&extraVarB=value2"; 

fileReference.upload(urlRequest);
```

then in the php script you just use

```
$_GET['extraValue']
$_GET['valueVarB']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply.Sorry for late.